# MongoDB & ElasticSearch configuration

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, collections, configuration, database

MongoDB is always showing me this error message when I insert any data in my collection.

I am trying to configure ElasticSearch with mongodb, when I realized my Replica. I try to add something, but no results.

Mongo Shell always shows me the same message:

```
WritResult({"writeError":{"code":undefined,"errmsg":"not master"}})
```

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you post an example of the code that leads to this error.

Comment: when I turn on my mongo shell me it displays this message: I CONTROL KB2731284 hotfix or later update is installed, no need to zero-out data files
MongoDB shell Version: 3.0.5
connecting to: test
> Use test
switched to db test
db.chose.save ({"name": "hjh", "first name": "kjkj"})
"WritResult ({" WriteError ": {" code ": undefined," errmsg ":" not master "}})"
>

Comment: If you want to know how to install properly, then follow the [guide](https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/wiki#install-guide)

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you do not have a 3 node Replica Set, and you start the replica in Master-Slave configuration and after that your master goes down or the secondary goes down. Since there is not third node or Arbiter to elect a new primary, the primary steps down as master and in pure read only mode. The only way to bring the replica set up is to create a new server with the same repl-set name and add the current stepped down master as secondary to it.